# Xcode send an SMS

Tags: xcode, sms

In my app, I want to be able to send an SMS. So when you press a button it will take you into the messaging area and will automatically put in a number and a message... If so could you please provide me with source code example on how to do this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) - it provides functionality you need and it is simple enough to use with just the reference at hand